# Swift 2.2 - uploadTaskWithRequest - How can I upload a text file from my app to my server

Tags: php, swift, api, file-upload, swift2

I'm really struggling to upload a text file from my apps documents directory to my php script. All I want to do is upload a text file from the app onto my server.

The Apple documentation makes it sound so simple but its just not in depth enough and I can't get it working so I'm hoping someone may be able to help.

Filtering out some of the classes and functions here is the main part of what I have in Swift 2.2:

```
lazy var config: NSURLSesionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
lazy var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: self.config, delgate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

let phpURL = "https://test-server.test/upload.php?"

let uploadStringURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: phpURL)!
let uploadRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: uploadStringURL)

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let docs = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .userDomainMask).first
let fullFilePath = docs!/URLByAppendingPathComponent("upload.dat")

uploadRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let uploadTask = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(uploadRequest, fromFile: fullFilePath, completionHandler: {(let data, let response, let error) in 

})

uploadTask.resume()
```

The uploadTask should be pushing the file to the server and it gets a response 200 showing that it was successful.

Here is the PHP part which I think is where the problem may lie:

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "/var/www/html/test-files/uploads";

    $target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    echo '{"target":'.$target_dir.'},';
    echo '{"base":'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]).'}';

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
        echo json_encode([
             "Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
             "Status" => "OK"
        ]);
    } 

    else {

        echo json_encode([
            "Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
            "Status" => "Error"
        ]);

    }
?>
```

I don't know too much about PHP but the $_FILES variable is blank.

Comment: Should add 'uploadtask.resume()'  at the end!

Comment: And session can be just nsurlsession.sharedsession().

Comment: @Krivvenz did you get this working?

Comment: @Wuno - Yes eventually! I ended up paying someone on Freelancer to show me how it's done. It's done via setting headers / http body tags like content-dispostion / content-type and attaching it to the upload request.

Comment: @Krivvenz that's great! I'm glad you got it working. Would you mind answering your own question on here? Showing some of your code in your solution? Or do you have an example on github?

Comment: Hi Wuno, normally I would but this post is 12 months old with only 253 views and not much activity. I now use Swift 3.0 (about to upgrade to Swift 4.0) as well so I think its probably best to just delete the post?